# constant pointers to constant arrays of constant pointers

Tags: c++, constants

we're learning about the `const` keyword in our object oriented c++ class.  Our professor says he's purposely going overboard to help us learn all the possible ways to use the `const` keyword.

In our assignment he states:

> Your constructor parameters should be constant pointers to constant
>   arrays of constant pointers

could somebody show me what an example of this parameter list would look like as well as explain what each const does?  I believe the prototype would look like this:

```
Square(const char* const []);
```

- where the first is for the pointer (in this case char*)
- second const is for the array
- but then I don't know where I would put the third const

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use the homework tag, as it's deprecated. Anyway, you might want to look into the spiral rule.

Comment: Are you sure it's "pointers to arrays", and not "pointers to the first element of an array"?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: they mean the same thing. on the other hand, there's technically no such thing as a constant array. only an array of constant elements

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah, I copy and pasted the quote from the assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see:

1. An array of pointers: `void * array[10];`
2. An array of constant pointers, same as a "constant array": `void * const array[10]`.
3. A pointer to the above: `void * const (*pa)[10] = &array;`
4. A *constant* pointer to (2): `void * const (* const pa)[10] = &array;`
5. A version of the above where the original array consists of pointers-to-const:

   ```
   void const * array2[15];

   void const * const (* const pa)[15] = &array2;
   ```

So here's your constructor signature, for any underlying type and array size:

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T, unsigned int N>
    Foo(T const * const (* const pa)[N]);

    // ...
};
```

As to what it's useful for: Pretty much nothing at all. But it can't hurt to understand this.

Answer (score -1):

It's a lot easier to read when written in C++, rather than C.

```
const std::array<const T, N>* const
```